# Multiple star-like looking objects moving across the sky

Tags: identify-this-object, movement

I know this question has been asked before, and not only on this resource. But none of the answers look satisfactory to my case.

So yesterday shortly after dusk, rouhgly around 18 UTC (local 21PM, I live in Ukraine), I observed a number of objects moving across the sky. In total, I counted 12 of them.
They were moving at more or less the same speed, though some of them were a bit faster (distance shortened), distances between objects vary, but in general the distance was rather big - during the movement, the first one disappeared while the last one had not yet arrived. I counted around 7-8 of them visible at the same time at the beginning, stretched across the sky. The latter ones were a bit delayed. It took several minutes for one object to cross the sky, like 3-4. Sadly, I wasn't smart enough (or too fascinated) to take exact measurements.

Their brightness reminded very much brightness of clearly visible stars with naked eye. I woud say somewhere around 1m (though this is very inaccurate), or maybe the brightness of Betelgeuse (but without reddish). (not as brigh as Venus, less bright then Sirius which was clearly visible at the time). The objects did not leave any trails and did not blink.
Jokes aside, I did not consume any drugs, alcohol or medicine that could change my perception of reality. Moreover, my significant one was nearby and also observed it.
So what could it be?

- Not a flock of birds - they do not fly stretched like that, and are not so bright at night.
- A group of satellites? Then, why are they so stretched? Is there a group that consists of 12 (or there might be more) units? What's the reason for some of them to be faster?
- Airplanes. These ones did not blink, and in general moved faster then airplane moves across the sky (unless it was some hypersonic aircraft group that do not have any blinking/colored lights on them).
- Some other flying objects.

Thanks!

Comment: well exactly now I am googling and found more precise information. So yes, it matches very much my observations, except that I estimated them 1m and they were closer to 2m. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=50.0515&lng=25.1801&loc=Unnamed&alt=0&tz=EET